# Matching strings in the same column using a large data set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to find out why does my code only return the first letter of each row as opposed to the longest matched string?
Im work with a large data set that consists of 1 column and 15,500 rows

```
 import csv
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df = pd.read_csv('newproducts.csv',error_bad_lines=False)df 
 df['onkey'] = 1
 df1 pd.merge(df[['name','onkey']],df[['name','onkey']], on='onkey')
 df1['list'] = df1.apply(lambda x:[x.name_x,x.name_y],axis=1)
 from os.path import commonprefix
 df1['COL1'] = df1['list'].apply(lambda x:commonprefix(x))
 df1['COL1_num'] = df1['COL1'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
 df1 = df1[(df1['COL1_num']!=0)]
 df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('name_x')['COL1_num'].idxmin()]
 df = df.rename(columns ={'name':'name_x'})
 df = pd.merge(df,df1[['name_x','COL1']],on='name_x',how ='left')


 df['len'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
 df['other'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.name_x[x.len:],axis=1)
 df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
 df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1]=='-' else x)
 df['other'] = df['other'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-'))
 df = df[['COL1','other']]
```

input 
So this would be the column you would start out with:
I would like to find the longest common strings  and put the parts that dont match into separate columns

```
product name
10 funniest Silicone Emperor - Ivory
10 funniest Stud 7 Inches - Hot Pink
10 funny elephant Hummer - Pink
10 funny elephant Hummer - Purple
10 Inch Realistic Dual Density Squirting snake
10 Inch Silicone Comfort Nozzle Attachment
10" comforter snake & comforter Bit Set - Black
10" comforter Jelly & comforter Bit Set - Pink
10" comforter Jelly & comforter Bit Set - Purple
10" Thick ladder W/balls & Suction - Black
100 insect magnets
1000 cloud Games
10-funniest Adonis Conqueror - Black
10-funniest Adonis Explorer - Red
10-funniest Adonis Vibrating Probe - Red
10-funniest Adonis Vibrating Strokers - Red
10-funniest Charisma Bliss - Black
10-funniest Charisma Bliss - Pink
10-funniest Charisma Kiss - Pink
10-funniest Charisma Tryst - Black
10-funniest Risque G-Vibe - Black
10-funniest Risque G-Vibe - Blue
10-funniest Risque G-Vibe - Purple
10-funniest Risque Slim - Black
10-funniest Risque Slim - Blue
10-funniest Risque Slim - Purple
10-funniest Risque Tulip - Black
10-funniest Risque Tulip - Blue
10-funniest Risque Tulip - Purple
```

output - the out put would be this with matches in 1 column and the parts that dont match in another column

```
new product name    
10 funniest Silicone Emperor     Ivory
10 funniest Stud 7 Inches    Hot Pink
10 funny elephant Hummer     Pink
10 funny elephant Hummer     Purple
10 Inch Realistic Dual Density Squirting snake  
10 Inch Silicone Comfort Nozzle Attachment  
10" comforter snake & comforter Bit Set      Black
10" comforter Jelly & comforter Bit Set      Pink
10" comforter Jelly & comforter Bit Set      Purple
10" Thick ladder W/balls & Suction   Black
100 insect magnets  
1000 cloud Games    
10-funniest Adonis Conqueror     Black
10-funniest Adonis Explorer      Red
10-funniest Adonis Vibrating Probe   Red
10-funniest Adonis Vibrating Strokers    Red
10-funniest Charisma Bliss   Black
10-funniest Charisma Bliss   Pink
10-funniest Charisma Kiss    Pink
10-funniest Charisma Tryst   Black
10-funniest Risque G-vibe    Black
10-funniest Risque G-vibe    Blue
10-funniest Risque G-vibe    Purple
10-funniest Risque Slim      Black
10-funniest Risque Slim      Blue
10-funniest Risque Slim      Purple
10-funniest Risque Tulip     Black
10-funniest Risque Tulip     Blue
10-funniest Risque Tulip     Purple
```

Comment: As just an observation, this code will be horrendously inefficient; `apply` is going to iterate the entire column _each time_ and in Python speed.

Comment: @roganjosh Im new to coding so Im very sorry. What would you suggest?I was thinking maybe use fuzzywuzzy, but have no experience with it

Comment: Don't be sorry! :) I'm actually looking through now and it looks like you have multiple string operations that I'm struggling to think of in a purely-pandas context. You _might_ actually be better doing this in pure Python but I will think some more yet. String operations are horribly slow in Pandas.

Comment: Is it possible to show us some sample data and an expected output?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not opposed to doing it purely in python,I think might be better for me to actually learn and get better at python. So definitely open to suggestions. :)

Comment: In that case, yes, it's useful if you could give an example input and output. Note that the `.str()` methods in Pandas are generally not vectorized (a common untruth that I am guilty of)

Comment: @chris it contains adult content is that ok to post?

Comment: @LondonHolder I would create a small sample df 5-10 rows it does not need to be your actual dataframe. It just needs to look similar to your actual dataframe as far as formatting and dtypes

Comment: @roganjosh I have just edited the question, please dont pay attention to the color changes, I'm not sure why it has done that.

Comment: @chris I edited the question I hope this ok, please forgive me for the way it looks

Comment: Quick note on SO formatting, separate to the question. Don't use backticks for code blocks, just copy/paste, highlight the whole block, and click the `{}` button in the editor, or use ctrl+k. Backticks are only good for single-line code.

Comment: And also, the blue highlighting is not your doing, that's just how it will be displayed :)

Comment: @roganjosh :) thank you so much for letting me know. Thanks for your patience.I will  fix it now.

Comment: And also also, I've just actually read the data and realised what we're answering on :P

Comment: I already fixed it.

Comment: @LondonHolder are you just looking for `df['product name'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)` ?

Comment: @chris i guess that would be part of the question but then some of the names have multiple dashes which would separate everything, which I dont want , i want it to keep the longest match  and separate what makes it different.

Comment: Your example output confuses me - it looks like you want to extract only the string containing color from a larger string? I don't see how 'longest matched string' comes into it.

Comment: @CJ59 These  are just examples ,sometimes its not just the color, it could be size, or some other variant. Also some are not separated by dashes.

Comment: You only have one `10 funniest Silicone Emperor` - the part I'm confused about is how you knew to keep that part in one column and then put `Ivory` in another column. Where is the matching part that you're talking about?

Comment: @cj59 So essentially i'm going to have to do some if/else statements at some point to handle cases as such, but the point of it is that it has "10 funniest" in it which is apart of several other names, also some name have more than one dash , aswell as I dont have a list of all the colors or 
 other variables  to find and remove them from the name.

Comment: @roganjosh any thoughts :P